# Wait for one or all LSF jobs to complete

Tags: cluster, hpc

With [Platform LSF](http://www.platform.com/Products/platform-lsf), is there a command that will wait for either a specific job or all my submitted jobs to finish before returning?  In other words, I am looking for the LSF equivalent of the `wait` built-in command in bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you give the `-K` option to `bsub`, it will wait for the job to complete before returning.  You can then background several `bsub` commands in the shell and use the shell's `wait` command to wait for them.  Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
bsub -K -o out.1 sleep 10 &
bsub -K -o out.2 sleep 5 &
wait
```

Comment: -K flag doesn't work if the bsub job is an array

Answer (score 4):

**`bwait`**

Example:

```
bsub -J 'myjobname' -o bsub.log bash -c 'date && sleep 10'
bwait -w 'ended(myjobname)'
```

The `bwait` waits until the corresponding `bsub` finished.

The same method also works for jobs arrays where `-K` is not supported:

```
bsub -J 'myjobname[1-40]' -o 'bsub%I.log" 'sleep $JOBINDEX && echo $JOBINDEX'
bwait -w 'ended(myjobname)'
```

Besides `ended()` there is also `done()` and `exit()`, which make `bwait` only exit successfully if the exit status is `0` or not `0` respectively, and otherwise fail with:

```
Wait condition is never satisfied
```

because LSF has different job states for both cases.

Related documentation:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bwait.1.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bsub.w.1.html#bsub_option_w

**`bsub -I`**

This is another good alternative to `-K` if you only have one job. E.g.:

```
bsub -I 'echo a;sleep 1;echo b;sleep 1;echo c'
echo done
```

prints stdout live to the terminal, and only runs `echo done` once the job finishes.

Documented at: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=options-i